Using one Background Check account for 2 entities
We have 2 entities now under us and seeing if we can use the same background check account that we utilize for both. I just want to make sure we are in compliance.

When you say 2 entities, do you mean something like two LLCs under a holding company of some sort? Basically something that is "XYZ a Z company" and "ABC a Z company".

This belongs on the legal site. This is not an employment issue. In my country this would be a serious violation. I think it would be in Europe too. A person authorises one company to do the check  on them, not other companies associated with it.
You can't share personal data. Unless you have prior written approval from that person.  Hire a lawyer before you get into trouble.

I am not a lawyer and I don't know your jurisdiction, so take this as a starting point. I am a business person.
That is really your choice based on your employment policies. If you document that you can share certain information with appropriately defined entities for specific purposes, then you can.
This is from a viewpoint of having recently completed a SOC-II Type 2 certification. That requires having just about every business process documented.
Bottomline is don't do it for one person and not the next. Inconsistency and lack of documentation is where the trouble begins.
